# Translating to Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator

I am taking the Learning Spatial Analyst course, which is very good but written for Version 9. I and my students are using Version 10, so some of the syntax for Raster Calculator have changed. Can anyone assist with translating these commands to Raster Calculator or point me to a document that updates them for Learning Spatial Analyst 9? The concepts are being emphasized in the course but its hard to get them without seeing the exercise results.

CON([DamBasin] AND ([DamElev] <= 790), 790)

CON(ISNULL([Reservoir]),[DamElev],790)

SetNull([Ownership] <> 200 OR [Soil] == 901, 1)

Comment: Thank you Michael! This is very helpful. Python is new to the class and me. For the last one, I got: SetNull([Ownership] <> 200 OR [Soil] == 901, 1)
Becomes
SetNull(("Ownership" != 200) | ("Soil" == 901),1)

Answer (score 5):

The translation isn't that difficult. The rasters are quoted not square bracketed, unless of course that's the correct syntax for a GRID which they appear to be:

```
CON([DamBasin] AND ([DamElev] <= 790), 790)
```

becomes

`Con("DamBasin" & ("DamElev" <= 790), 790)` assuming DamBasin is binary.. true is 790, false is nodata

```
CON(ISNULL([Reservoir]),[DamElev],790)
```

becomes

```
Con(IsNull("Reservoir"),"DamElev",790)
```

If the square brackets are correct for GRID raster type then they are correct already.